# "function public.pg_stat_statements_reset() does not exist" error on restoring dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am taking dump of a database using pg_dump using this command

`pg_dump -U [username] -h <[hostname] -p [port] -v [database_name] > dump.sql`

and restoring to a new database with

`psql -U [username] -h [hostname] -p [port] [database_name] < dump.sql`

and I am getting this error when restoring the dump:

`ERROR:  function public.pg_stat_statements_reset() does not exist`

I found some answers related to this which does the following:

1. Install pg_stat_statements extension - In my case this is already installed

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions 
WHERE 
    name = 'pg_stat_statements' and 
    installed_version is not null;
```

this query yields:

```
name        | default_version | installed_version |                                comment                                 
--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
 pg_stat_statements | 1.9             | 1.9               | track planning and execution statistics of all SQL statements executed
```

2. My pg.conf file already contains the line:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.track = all
```

Tried backup in pgadmin in custom, Tar and Plain Formats and it didn't help
Also with pg_restore.
Restoring with 'postgres' user which has superuser privileges

Please help resolve this. TIA.

Comment: You said "Install pg_stat_statements extension - In my case this is already installed" -- on both the original database and the new database?

Comment: Yes, both the original and new.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the extension availability in the same database in which you are restoring and postgres database.